# How to send an array struct into a function using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

How to send an array of structs into a function as a parameter?

The employee variable is a struct. 
My function:

```cpp
void arraySort(struct Employee *employee[])
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        int empID1 = employee[i]->empID;
        int empID2 = employee[i + 1]->empID;
        flag = Employee().compareEmpID(empID1, empID2);
        if (flag == true)
        {
            Employee swap;
            swap = *employee[i + 1];
            *employee[i] = *employee[i + 1];
            *employee[i + 1] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

Which calls this function:

```cpp
bool Employee::compareEmpID(int empID1, int empID2)
{
    if (empID1 >= empID2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I am trying to invoke a call to the arraySorts function from main by using the employee array struct as a pointer:

```cpp
arraySort(*employee);
```

Comment: A few issues with your question...  Firstly, you haven't actually asked one -- you only said what you're trying to do.  And we don't know what is the actual type of `employee` at the place where you say you're calling `arraySort(*employee)`.  My gut says you're confused about pointer dereferencing, and you should be calling `arraySort(employee)`.  But you should really show us the definition of `employee`.  Note that you are assuming this array contains _at least_ 5001 valid elements.  If it contains less than that, your `arraySort` function will run off the end of the array.

Comment: You need to show what is `employee` variable. Without knowing its type, we can't answer. EDIT: I see you edited the post to say it is a "struct" type, but we need to see how you are declaring it.

Comment: As a side note, this function doesn't actually sort an array.  It only makes a single pass through the array, similar to one of the steps in bubble sort or selection sort.

Comment: Whoops, edited. The employee variable is an array of structs.

Comment: No, "the employee variable is an array of structs" is not the _definition_.  We are asking for the actual code where you define this array.  Your `arraySort` function accepts an array of `Employee` _pointers_.  What's more, you haven't stated what the actual problem is.  Are you getting a compiler error?  If so, you should show the full text of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The function compareEmpID have to be a static method in struct employee and invoked by calling as `Employee::compareEmpID`.
There are some issues in for your arraySort method.

- You hard code the number 5000, that means your array need to have 5000 elements or more, otherwise you will get error about illegal memory access.
- The variable swap should be a pointer and declared outside of the for loop.
- Your swap logic is wrong.

I rewrite the program base on your code and tested it.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Employee {
    int empID;
    static bool compareEmpID(int empID1, int empID2) {
        return empID1 > empID2;
    }
};

void arraySort(Employee *employees[], int size) {
    bool flag = false;
    Employee *swap;

    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++) {
        int empID1 = employees[i]->empID;
        int empID2 = employees[i+1]->empID;
        flag = Employee::compareEmpID(empID1,empID2);
        if(flag) {
            swap = employees[i+1];
            employees[i+1] = employees[i];
            employees[i] = swap;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    Employee** employee;
    employee = new Employee*[2];
    employee[0] = new Employee;
    employee[0]->empID = 5;
    employee[1] = new Employee;
    employee[1]->empID = 1;
    arraySort(employee, 2);
    cout << "emp[0]: " << employee[0]->empID << endl;
    cout << "emp[1]: " << employee[1]->empID << endl;
    delete employee[0];
    delete employee[1];
    delete[] employee;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps you boots your learning progress.